# linux bash syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

I faced a strange error while running a bash script:

> : No such file or directorydata0/backup/daily
>
> remotebackup.sh: line 41: syntax error: unexpected end of file

The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
##Notification email address
_EMAIL=bonheurswp@gmail.com
ERRORLOG=/var/log/backuplogs/backup.err`date +%F`
ACTIVITYLOG=/var/log/backuplogs/activity.log`date +%F`

SOURCE=/data0/backup/daily

DBNAME=vihomes_ads
SQLFILE=vihomes_ads.sql

BUCKETNAME=hontoot
FOLDERNAME=ads

DESTINATION=`date +%F`

DEGREE=30
#Clear the logs if the script is executed second time
:> ${ERRORLOG}
:> ${ACTIVITYLOG}
# Backup the source files using tar.
tar -zcf ${SOURCE}/htads.tar.gz /data0/www/htads 1>>${ACTIVITYLOG} 2>>${ERRORLOG}
# Dump database into SQL file
mysqldump --user=user_for_ads --password=sa987@Rt#69 ${DBNAME} > ${SOURCE}/${SQLFILE}1>>${ACTIVITYLOG} 2>>${ERRORLOG}
##Uploading the daily backup to Amazon s3
/usr/bin/s3cmd -r put ${SOURCE} s3://${BUCKETNAME}/${FOLDERNAME}/${DESTINATION}/ 1>>${ACTIVITYLOG} 2>>${ERRORLOG} ret2=$?
##Sent email alert
msg="BACKUP NOTIFICATION ALERT FROM `hostname`"
if [ $ret2 -eq 0 ];then
msg1="Amazon s3 Backup Uploaded Successfully"
else
msg1="Amazon s3 Backup Failed!!\n Check ${ERRORLOG} for more details"
fi
echo -e "$msg1"|mail -s "$msg" ${_EMAIL}
#######################
##Deleting backup's older than DEGREE days
## Delete from both server and amazon
#######################
DELETENAME=$(date  --date="${DEGREE} days ago" +%F)
/usr/bin/s3cmd -r --force del s3://${BUCKETNAME}/${FOLDERNAME}/${DELETENAME} 1>>${ACTIVITYLOG} 2>>${ERRORLOG}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing quote, a `fi`, a closing parentheses, or something like that. Your script also has DOS line endings.

Comment: Hi Arkascha, the line 41 is the last line.

Answer (score 2):

The primary problem is that your script has DOS/Windows-style line endings (carriage return followed by linefeed). bash expects unix-style line endings (just linefeed), and interprets the carriage return as part of the command, leading to much confusion. The giveaway is this error message:

```
: No such file or directorydata0/backup/daily
```

The ": No such file or directory" part is supposed to come *after* the nonexistent file name, but because the filename was set by the command `SOURCE=/data0/backup/daily<CR>`, the carriage return makes it print the end of the message over the beginning of it.

This also leads to problems with keywords, like in the line

```
if [ $ret2 -eq 0 ];then<CR>
```

...bash doesn't recognize `then<CR>` as the `then` keyword, it thinks it's just part of the if clause. And it gets to the end of the file *still* looking for its `then` keyword, and since it never saw it you get an unexpected end of file error.

So fix the line endings (with `dos2unix`, or its equivalent on your OS), and stop using editors that save in DOS/Windows format.

BTW, I also noticed that in the line

```
/usr/bin/s3cmd -r put ${SOURCE} s3://${BUCKETNAME}/${FOLDERNAME}/${DESTINATION}/ 1>>${ACTIVITYLOG} 2>>${ERRORLOG} ret2=$?
```

`ret2=$?` really should be a separate command.